# [php]remove html code from string

Tags: php, regex, dom, phpquery

in this variable: $this->item->text I have this string:

```
<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) starts here -->

<div class="itp-fshare-floating" id="itp-fshare" style="position:fixed; top:30px !important; left:50px !important;"></div><p>Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblòdei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”,</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span class="easy_img_caption" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:150px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;"><a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8:recensione&catid=3:recensione-dei-servizi-di-cloud-computing&Itemid=4"><img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/8428e9c26f1d8498ece730c0aa6aa023.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1"  style="width:150px; height:120px; ;margin:0;" /></a><span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1</span></span></p>
<p>che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker</p>

<!-- Disqus comments counter and anchor link -->
<a class="jwDisqusListingCounterLink" href="http://clouderize.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8:recensione&catid=3:recensione-dei-servizi-di-cloud-computing&Itemid=4#disqus_thread" title="Add a comment">
    Add a comment</a>

<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) ends here -->

<div class="cp_tags">
<span class="cp_tag_label">Tags: </span><span class="cp_tag cp_tag_6"><a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_customproperties&task=tag&tagId=6&Itemid=1">Recensioni</a>
</span> </div>
```

So with this code I extract

```
<span class="easy_img_caption......></span>
```

Code (I am using this library called phpQuery http://goo.gl/rSu3k):

```
include_once('includes/phpQuery.php');
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($this->item->text);
$extraction=pq('.easy_img_caption:eq(0)')->htmlOuter();
echo"<textarea>".$extraction."</textarea>";
```

So my question is:
How can I remove $extraction string from $this->item->text?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very inprecise. What is `phpQuery.php`? Is it [jQuery port to PHP called phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume phpQuery is some library aiding with dom-parsing in php?

Anyway, to accomplish this, you don't exactly need this external library. It can easily be accomplished with a regular expression replace:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<span.*?class="[^"]*?easy_img_caption[^"]*?".*?>.*?<\/span>/s', '', $this->item->text);
echo "<textarea>" . $text . "</textarea>";
```

Comment: How have you build the regex expression? Does it exist some tools?

Comment: Thought you wanted to remove this span out of the entire string.
To actually fetch only that string, use the same regex, but with function preg_match (rather than preg_replace)

Comment: mlitn If I want to remove <a class="jwDisqusListingCounterLink" .... how can I do the regex?

Comment: preg_replace('/<a.*?class="[^"]*?jwDisqusListingCounterLink[^"]*?".*?>.*?<\/a>/s', '', $this->item->text);

Comment: With this string http://codepad.org/UyxD7qgP  your regex delete wrong span...why?